# How to use map for lowercase or uppercase in Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I'm using java stream and I have a problem. I have this code:

```
clients.stream()
                    .map(Client::getDescription)
                    .map(x -> x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("_v")))
                    .map(x -> x.substring(2))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .max()
                    .getAsInt();
```

The description for every client could be "John_abc_v1", "Bill_crce_v2", "Joe_ghhj_V3"... and I get the maximum, in this case 3... but the problem is that v could be lowercase or uppercase and I don't know how to resolve that, so this line is not working                     `.map(x -> x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("_v")))` I get `String index out of range -1` when "V" is uppercase. How can I resolve that? Any feedback will be apreciated.

Comment: Convert everything to lowercase first?

Comment: You don't need 2 maps for the `substring` ones: `x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(...) + 2)`.

Comment: You could also do `x.replaceAll(".*(\d+)$", "$1")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various approaches, these are just a few:

1. Lowercase the entire string, as suggested by [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266604/how-to-use-map-for-lowercase-or-uppercase-in-java-8-streams#comment120651010_68266604). This means the `V` would be converted to `v`, so you could find it with `lastIndexOf`.
2. Use regex to replace the parts of the string you don't want, i.e. everything but the trailing digits:

   ```
   .map(x -> x.replaceAll(".*(\\d+)$", "$1"))
   ```

   It then doesn't matter about the case of the `V`.
3. Write a little method which finds the trailing digits:

   ```
   String trailingDigits(String x) {
     int last = x.length();
     while (last > 0 && Character.isDigit(x.charAt(last - 1)) {
       --last;
     }
     return x.substring(last);
   }
   ```

   and call from your map:

   ```
   .map(x -> trailingDigits(x))
   ```

Comment: The backslash should be escaped in the regex... Maybe you want to add `[vV]` explicitly.

Comment: @Matt I don't think the `V` is important per se; it's just what happens to come before the trailing digits.

Comment: Java 9 introduced [`Integer.parseInt(s,beginIndex,endIndex,radix))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,int)) which allows to skip the `substring` operation. So you could change `String trailingDigits(String x)` to `static int trailingNumber(String x)` and its `return x.substring(last);` to `return Integer.parseInt( x, last, x.length(), 10);`. Then, a single `mapToInt(ContainingClass::trailingNumber)` would be sufficient… For Java 8, I’d still use a `trailingNumber` method doing the `substring`/`parseInt`…